# telnet aspmx.l.google.com and it try ipv6 first

Tags: linux, telnet

well, I try to send email via google 'aspmx.l.google.com' server, port 25. I can send emial, technically. I just have to wait one minute to wait the sending process complete.

Then I try to do telnet to aspmx.l.google.com from my terminal and I found that it tries ipv6 first and then tries ipv4 after ipv6 is timeout.

I believe that is why I need to wait a minute for sending email.

BTW: I am doing it locally.

Does anyone know what is the real problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix your IPv6 connectivity problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer your question with questions...

Which IPv6 address is it returning?  Same as I get?

> aspmx.l.google.com.   293 IN  AAAA    2a00:1450:4013:c00::1a

Can you force ipv4 for your email server instead of trying to use ipv6 to verify that this is really your issue?  Does your mail log's timestamps show a one minute delay even with ipv4 forced?

See here if you are using Postfix: http://linuxmoz.com/google-mail-ipv6-network-is-unreachable-postfix-ipv4-only-fix/

Comment: if I try: 'telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25', I wll get 'Trying 2607:f8b0:400d:c00::1b...', after 1 minute, it will try '173.194.76.26...', then it works

Comment: Are you using postfix?  Can you force ipv4 in your email server and see if it doesn't delay 1 minute?

Comment: I am not using postfix. By forcing use ipv4 is exact what I want. Actually, the point is that I am developing locally and running it somewhere at AWS instance. On the AWS instance, it is fine. So somehow I can just leave with it locally. However, we just want to know why, on my local machine, it will try ipv6 first than try ipv4.

Comment: If you have ipv6 enabled on your local computer since Google supports ipv6 it will try to resolve/connect using ipv6 first.  You can disable ipv6 on your local machine to verify/test if you want.

Comment: I seems know how to solve it, just uncomment precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100 in my /etc/gai.conf file.

Comment: It works. It is not that hard, just let my machine know I prefer ipv4 than ipv6